# C# ConfigurationManager Problem

Tags: c#, .net, configurationmanager

I have upgrade the project from framework3.5 to framework4.0.Right Now i am using Visual studio 2010.Here is my app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
 <appSettings>
<add key="DBConnectionString" value="User ID=sa;Password=password123;Initial   Catalog=DishTV_Voting;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=ENMEDIA-50CB48D"/>
 </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

Here when i am working with framework 3.5 I used the config file as

```
  using  System.Configuration;
namespace Voting_Editor_Tool_New
{
public partial class Voting_Editor_Tool : Form
{
    SqlConnection myConnection;

    string connectString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBConnectionString"];
  public void getdata()
  {



   myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectString); 
     ....
   } 
 }
}
```

When I upgrade to framework 4.0 the line

```
   ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBConnectionString"];
```

shows a warning message as

'System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings' is obsolete: 'This method is obsolete, it has been replaced by System.Configuration!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings'.

I tried with ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnectionString"]; but it shows a error
as

```
The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context
```

Can anyone just how to solve the problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are referencing `System.Configuration` 4.0. Try to remove the existing reference, and add the latest version of it again.

Then you can get the actual connection string, and create an SQL connection as such:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    // do stuff
}
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)

Comment: Here after adding the using System.Configuration;It doesn't show ConfigurationManager inside the System.Configuration library.

Comment: What version of System.Configuration are you trying to reference? Can you remove it and add the correct one again?

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a reference the [System.configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings.aspx is in the system.dll ConfigurationManger is the the configuration dll namespaces can be defined across assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved my problem changing the string "connectString" for the really string that is the address of your DB.

Exemple: this =  **myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectString);**
For this = **myConnection = new SqlConnection("User ID=sa;Password=password123;Initial   Catalog=DishTV_Voting;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=ENMEDIA-50CB48D")**

In my case works perfect